# Parsing .xml file and converting to data frame with duplicate column scripts

Tags: r

Trying to extract data from xml files. Subset of xml is:

```
<Table>
      <CaptionLeft>Fluorometer 2 Background Offsets</CaptionLeft>
      <Scan iter="1" date="08-May-2019">
        <Result color="FAM" value="290"/>
        <Result color="HEX" value="47"/>
        <Result color="ROX" value="59"/>
        <Result color="RED647" value="41"/>
        <Result color="RED677" value="1053"/>
      </Scan>
    </Table>
    <Table>
      <Scan iter="1" date="08-May-2019">
        <Result color="FAM" value="17038"/>
        <Result color="HEX" value="2476"/>
        <Result color="ROX" value="1279"/>
        <Result color="RED647" value="845"/>
        <Result color="RED677" value="1369"/>
      </Scan>
      <CaptionLeft>Fluorometer 2 PEEK Lid RFU Average</CaptionLeft>
    </Table>
    <Table>
      <CaptionLeft>Dirty Fibers Check</CaptionLeft>
      <Scan iter="1" date="08-May-2019">
        <Result color="FAM" value="PASS"/>
        <Result color="HEX" value="PASS"/>
        <Result color="ROX" value="PASS"/>
        <Result color="RED647" value="PASS"/>
        <Result color="RED677" value="PASS"/>
      </Scan>
    </Table>
```

Specifically I want to store the background offset color and associated value in the file. I cannot convert to a dataframe as the have duplicate columns.

I can get ever 'color' and associated 'value' from the Result nodeset but I do not know how to get the  for each of the tables

```
a1 <- xpathSApply(doc, "//Result", xmlAncestors, xmlAttrs)
a1_len <- lengths( a1 )
nm <- make.unique( names( a1[[ which( a1_len == max( a1_len ))[1] ]] ) )
a1 <- lapply( a1, function( x ) {
  require('data.table')
  nm_x <- make.unique( names(x) )

  if( ! all( nm %in% nm_x ) ) {
    x [ (nm [ which( ! nm %in% nm_x ) ]) ] <- NA
  }

  x <- cbind.data.frame( x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
  colnames( x ) <- make.unique( colnames( x ) )
  setDT(x)
  setcolorder( x, nm )
  return( x ) 
})

a1 <- rbindlist( a1 )
a1
```

::

```
a1
     iter        date  color value  bad
  1:    1 08-May-2019    FAM  100% <NA>
  2:    1 08-May-2019    HEX  100% <NA>
  3:    1 08-May-2019    ROX  100% <NA>
  4:    1 08-May-2019 RED647  100% <NA>
  5:    1 08-May-2019 RED677  100% <NA>
 ---                                   

Hoping for something like below

    CaptionLeft                            iter        date  color value  bad
  1:Fluorometer 2 Background Offsets         1 08-May-2019    FAM  100% <NA>
  2:Fluorometer 2 Background Offsets         1 08-May-2019    HEX  100% <NA>
  3:Fluorometer 2 Background Offsets         1 08-May-2019    ROX  100% <NA>
  4:Fluorometer 2 Background Offsets         1 08-May-2019 RED647  100% <NA>
  5:Fluorometer 2 Background Offsets         1 08-May-2019 RED677  100% <NA>
```

Comment: Why %100 is appearing in value column? And what is bad column? Do you want to get 5 data for each CaptionLeft which is 15 in total for this example?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my xml file contains a total of 29 of these tables, each of which had 5 colors with associated values.  Some of the values are integers, some are percents and some are 'pass' or 'fail'.  In the example I only showed 1 of the 29 tables, this one happens to present %, here is the xml portion that would generate that:

Comment: For some of the table, bad is another node, similar to value, for each color, but not all tables have this so it returns NA in the tables that dont, typically it will results in 'true' or 'false'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this works for your.

```
library(xml2)
library(magrittr)

#I put your example data into `test.xml`

doc <- read_xml( "./desktop/test.xml" )
tables <- xml_find_all(doc, "//Table")

df <- lapply(1:length(tables), function(i) {


    data.frame(CaptionLeft=xml_text(tables[[i]]),
              iter =    xml_attr(xml_find_first(tables[[i]], "//Scan"),"iter") %>% as.numeric,
              date = xml_attr(xml_find_first(tables[[i]], "//Scan"),"date"),
               color = xml_attr(xml_children(xml_find_all(tables[i],"//Result/parent::Scan")[[i]]),"color"),
               value = xml_attr(xml_children(xml_find_all(tables[i],"//Result/parent::Scan")[[i]]),"value"),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    

})


df <- do.call(rbind,df)
```

**Output :**

```
                          CaptionLeft iter        date  color value
1    Fluorometer 2 Background Offsets    1 08-May-2019    FAM   290
2    Fluorometer 2 Background Offsets    1 08-May-2019    HEX    47
3    Fluorometer 2 Background Offsets    1 08-May-2019    ROX    59
4    Fluorometer 2 Background Offsets    1 08-May-2019 RED647    41
5    Fluorometer 2 Background Offsets    1 08-May-2019 RED677  1053
6  Fluorometer 2 PEEK Lid RFU Average    1 08-May-2019    FAM 17038
7  Fluorometer 2 PEEK Lid RFU Average    1 08-May-2019    HEX  2476
8  Fluorometer 2 PEEK Lid RFU Average    1 08-May-2019    ROX  1279
9  Fluorometer 2 PEEK Lid RFU Average    1 08-May-2019 RED647   845
10 Fluorometer 2 PEEK Lid RFU Average    1 08-May-2019 RED677  1369
11                 Dirty Fibers Check    1 08-May-2019    FAM  PASS
12                 Dirty Fibers Check    1 08-May-2019    HEX  PASS
13                 Dirty Fibers Check    1 08-May-2019    ROX  PASS
14                 Dirty Fibers Check    1 08-May-2019 RED647  PASS
15                 Dirty Fibers Check    1 08-May-2019 RED677  PASS
```